# Integrating a smooth family of differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry

I have been trying to find a reference for the following :

> Suppose I have a smooth family of differential forms $\omega_t$ that are exact. Then we can find a smooth family of differential forms $\mu_t$ such that $d\mu_t=\omega_t$.

I have been told this can be found in Bott and Tu's differential froms in algebraic topology but I could't find it anywhere . Does anyone know the specific chapter or another reference for this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at the Poincaré lemma?

Comment: Yes I did . How does it help me ? @TedShifrin

Comment: Yes, of course you're right. The form on $M\times I$ will likely not be closed. You should look at the various posts referring to Moser's trick.